# Getting coordinates of ways in *.pbf file?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I would like to extract some lines and polygons from OSM data (In the format of `.pbf`). After using `osmosis` I can get a osm file with all the elements like this:

```
<way id="102670197" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-04T12:10:15Z" uid="49111" user="Markus B" changeset="7453788">
    <nd ref="1185769039"/>
    <nd ref="1185769259"/>
    <nd ref="1185768938"/>
    <nd ref="1185768893"/>
    <nd ref="1185769039"/>
    <tag k="sport" v="tennis"/>
    <tag k="leisure" v="pitch"/>
</way>
```

I understand that if I use Overpass API I can get the coordinates according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297077 but I am wondering whether I can use some osm tools to get the coordinates from the `.pbf` file.

Comment: My command is as follows: ```osmosis --read-pbf area.pbf --tf reject-nodes --tf reject-relations completeWays=yes --tf accept-ways amenity=* --write-xml output.osm```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Osmosis takes all nodes to the output file, unless you add the `--used-node` options. `--tf reject-nodes` discards all nodes, including those of your ways. If the way leaves your bounding box or polygon, `completeWays=yes` might be useful too.

As an example:

```
 osmosis.bat --read-pbf germany-latest.osm.pbf --tf accept-ways man_made=pipeline --tf reject-relations --used-node  --write-xml de-pipeline.osm
```

Osmfilter works similar, but you have to convert from .pbf to .osm or .o5m with osmconvert first. In most cases, osmfilter is quicker than osmosis.